# SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, starttls, horde

I have a problem, i made a command "openssl s_client -connect server.server:143", and the error is:

```
  CONNECTED(00000003)
140719622096768:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown proto col:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 249 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I made that because the horde connection gives an error in login.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> openssl s_client -connect server.server:143

Port 143 is plain IMAP, that is you can not talk directly TLS to this port. If you try it you will get some data back which are not TLS, and thus strange error messages will occure. If you want to have TLS you have to either use imaps (port 993) or issue a STARTTLS command. You can also use openssl for this with

```
openssl s_client -connect server:143 -starttls imap
```

From your output it might even be that you used this option but did not put it into your question (because 7 bytes from the server would match a TLS alert, but is unusually short for an IMAP greeting). If this is the case there might be lots of reasons why the connection fails and it is not possible to pin the problem down just from your description. If you get more help look at http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html#hdr2.2 on how you could narrow down the problem and what you should provide on information if you need help from others.

Comment: Yes, it's all okay with that command i think.I'm trying to make login in horde , with a webmail created by cyradm in the server.server . I made login and in /var/log/maillog appears:
imaps TLS negotiation failed: server.server
FATAL error: tls_start_servertls() failed. And i can't understand my problem.

Comment: Again, these are way to few information to debug the problem. Look at the link I've provided which information you should collect. If the server is public you may also provide its name so one could check the problem. If you have access to the server you should also look at the error messages in the server log file.